# How to stop mathematica from exchanging my matrices this way ?

Tags: algebra

Mathematica is exchanging the matrices i have written in a way that makes my equation doesn't make sense as the dimensions do not match anymore. I want the order of my Matrices to stay the same. 
 [image: enter code here]

Comment: You are using plain multiplication (`Times`, or `*`), not matrix multiplication (`Dot`, or `.`), so Mathematica is correctly interpreting it as commutative.

Comment: While not listed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/52) this is a _very_ common mistake.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much :)